# Assigning Value to unsigned long long in C

Tags: c, long-integer

While assigning value to a unsigned long long variable in C, value of variable is not getting assigned properly. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned long long x;
  printf("%d\n\n",sizeof(x));
  x=0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL;
  printf("%u\n\n",x);
  printf("%ld\n\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Rightmost 32 bits of the variable are being ignored. Can someone please tell me how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Print `unsigned long long` with `%llu`.

Answer (score 3):

Use llu or Lu format specifier for printf if you want to print unsigned long long. The format specifier depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment occurs correctly.  However, the program is not displaying the value correctly.

```
printf("%Lu\n\n",x);
```

or

```
printf("%llu\n\n",x);
```

or maybe even

```
printf("%LLu\n\n",x);
```

depending on the compiler and specific runtime library.

Comment: @izomorphius:  I think it was System V, or maybe a customized BSD I used at Intel's SSD division (hundreds of CPUs meshed together).  It was at least 20 years ago.

Comment: @RogMatthews:  If you mean the suffix to the literal constant, then yes:  type promotion from an integer to a bigger integer is always done as needed.  However, that constant is pretty large.  Some compilers might give a warning or error and insist on an explicit size suffix.  The better compilers won't.

Comment: @wallyk Just now, as an example, I needed to add explicit casting to get the MSVS2010 C++ compiler to do the right thing. I'd assume the same thing would be needed if I happened to compile C code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `printf`s to print properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long x;
    printf("%d\n\n",sizeof(x));
    x=0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL;
    printf("%u\n\n",x);  // not work
    printf("%llu\n\n",x);  // works
    printf("%016llx\n\n",x); // bonus check
    return 0;
}
```